# statistics chart in splunk using value from log

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to Splunk dashboard. I need some help with this kind of data.

```
2020-09-22 11:14:33.328+0100 org{abc}  INFO  3492 --- [hTaskExecutor-1] c.j.a.i.p.v.b.l.ReadFileStepListener     : [] read-feed-file-step ended with status exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription= with compositeReadCount 1 and other count status as: BatchStatus(readCount=198, multiEntityAccountCount=0, readMultiAccountEntityAdjustment=0, accountFilterSkipCount=7, broadRidgeFilterSkipCount=189, writeCount=2, taskCreationCount=4)
```

I wanted to have statistics in a dashboard showing all the integer values in the above log.

**Edit 1:**

I tried this but not working.

```
index=abc xyz| rex field=string .*readCount=(?P<readCount>\d+)  | table readCount
```

Comment: Is that a single log entry or multiple entries?  Are fields already extracted?
What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: this would be single entry per day when the batch job will run. I want something which can be easily visualized to get different counts like a number of records in the file, counts for skipped records...These numbers are present in the log in single line

Answer (score 0):

See if this run-anywhere example helps.

```
| makeresults 
| eval _raw="2020-09-22 11:14:33.328+0100 org{abc}  INFO  3492 --- [hTaskExecutor-1] c.j.a.i.p.v.b.l.ReadFileStepListener     : [] read-feed-file-step ended with status exitCode=COMPLETED;exitDescription= with compositeReadCount 1 and other count status as: BatchStatus(readCount=198, multiEntityAccountCount=0, readMultiAccountEntityAdjustment=0, accountFilterSkipCount=7, broadRidgeFilterSkipCount=189, writeCount=2, taskCreationCount=4)"
`comment("Everything above just sets up test data")`
| extract kvdelim=",", pairdelim="="
| timechart span=1h max(*Count) as *Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using

```
index=xyz |regex ".*fileName=(\s*([\S\s]+))" | rex field=string .*compositeReadCount=(?P<compositeReadCount>\d+)  |regex ".*readCount=(?P<readCount>\d+)" | regex ".*multiEntityAccountCount=(?P<multiEntityAccountCount>\d+)" | regex ".*readMultiAccountEntityAdjustment=(?P<readMultiAccountEntityAdjustment>\d+)" | regex ".*accountFilterSkipCount=(?P<accountFilterSkipCount>\d+)" | regex ".*broadRidgeFilterSkipCount=(?P<broadRidgeFilterSkipCount>\d+)" | regex ".*writeCount=(?P<writeCount>\d+)" | regex ".*taskCreationCount=(?P<taskCreationCount>\d+)" | regex ".*status=(\s*([\S\s]+))" | table _time fileName compositeReadCount readCount multiEntityAccountCount readMultiAccountEntityAdjustment accountFilterSkipCount broadRidgeFilterSkipCount writeCount taskCreationCount status
```